# Clear the focus from the edittext in listview

Tags: android

I have a listview where each row will have edittext. When I click on edit text keypad comes. And then when I click on back button to close keypad I want to clear the focus.

since the listview layout is used in adapter, I am not able to do it in activity.

Please help.

~Cheers
Prakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to clear the focus of your edit text:

```
private int tempHeight = 0;
private Rect r = null;

public void gettingStatusOfKeyboard() {
    final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    r = new Rect();
    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    tempHeight = r.bottom;

    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            if(tempHeight == r.bottom){
                usernameEdit.setFocusable(false);
                passwordEdit.setFocusable(false);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```